# Making Owl Carousel Liquid / work in percentages?

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have installed owl carousel and it works very well. Im happy with the plugin but what bothers me is that it does not scale with the viewport. I want it to become smaller together with the items the smaller my viewport becomes. I tried setting responsive: "false". Then I added a custom percentage width for the **.owl-item** class with !important. It works for items but they dont scale since the sliding stage or **.owl-wrapper** is in PX. I tried overriding it with a width of 400% or so but then the problem is that I  cant slide to the last item.

Here a clean JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Epmwx/83/

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item{
    float: left;width:4% !important
}

.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{
    width:400% !important
}
```

I would appreciate if you would show me what I am doing wrong. Why cant I make it fully liquid? I didnt add it on my jsfiddle but could that problem be only when trying to do a liquid image slider?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little tricky to work out exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but if you are trying to replicate the [responsive functionality on the Owl Carousel Page](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html), note that the `responsive` key is not boolean, but an object denoting breakpoints and behaviour.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Epmwx/84/)

```
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1,
        nav:true
    },
    600:{
        items:3,
        nav:false
    },
    1000:{
        items:5,
        nav:true,
        loop:false
    }
}
```

You can style the carousel (and the individual items) at each specified breakpoint by also setting `responsiveClass:true`, from the [API docs](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html):

> responsiveClass:
>
> Optional helper class. Add 'owl-reponsive-' + 'breakpoint' class to
>   main element.